# How do I migrate an existing production database with Liquibase and JHipster?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, jhipster, liquibase

I'm trying to update my [21-points.com](http://www.21-points.com) app to use the [latest code](https://github.com/mraible/21-points) from the [JHipster Mini-Book](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/jhipster-4-mini-book). Here’s what I’ve done so far:

1. Use Heroku’s `pg:pull` command to copy my production database to a local database:

   ```
   heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL health --app health-by-points
   ```
2. Installed Liquibase and copied the PostgreSQL database driver into $LIQUIBASE_HOME/lib.

   ```
   [mraible:/opt/tools/liquibase-3.5.3-bin] % cp ~/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.4.1212/postgresql-9.4.1212.jar lib/.
   ```
3. Ran liquibase’s “diffChangeLog” to generate a changelog to migrate from old database to new schema.

   ```
   ./liquibase \
   --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/health --username=postgres \
   diffChangeLog \
   --referenceUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/twentyonepoints \
   --referenceUsername=twentyonepoints --referencePassword=21points
   ```
4. Copied output to `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/20171024115100_migrate_from_v2.xml` and added to `config/liquibase/master.xml`.
5. Changed `application-prod.xml` in my latest-and-greatest JHipster app to point to old database that I downloaded from Heroku.
6. Ran `./gradlew -Pprod`. Error on startup:

   ```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/jhipster/health/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
    2 change sets check sum
         config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000000::jhipster was: 7:eda8cd7fd15284e6128be97bd8edea82 but is now: 7:a6235f40597a13436aa36c6d61db2269
         config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001::jhipster was: 7:e87abbb935c561251405aea5c91bc3a4 but is now: 7:29cf7a7467c2961e7a2366c4347704d7
   ```
7. Ran the following commands to update the md5sum’s in the database.

   ```
   update databasechangelog set md5sum = '7:a6235f40597a13436aa36c6d61db2269' where md5sum = '7:eda8cd7fd15284e6128be97bd8edea82';
   update databasechangelog set md5sum = '7:29cf7a7467c2961e7a2366c4347704d7' where md5sum = '7:e87abbb935c561251405aea5c91bc3a4’;
   ```
8. Tried to run again.

   ```
   2017-10-24 12:12:02.670 ERROR 22960 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20160831020048_added_entity_Points.xml::20160831020048-1::jhipster: Change Set config/liquibase/changelog/20160831020048_added_entity_Points.xml::20160831020048-1::jhipster failed.  Error: ERROR: relation "points" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.points (id BIGINT NOT NULL, jhi_date date NOT NULL, exercise INT, meals INT, alcohol INT, notes VARCHAR(140), user_id BIGINT, CONSTRAINT PK_POINTS PRIMARY KEY (id))]
   2017-10-24 12:12:02.672  WARN 22960 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/jhipster/health/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20160831020048_added_entity_Points.xml::20160831020048-1::jhipster:
    Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "points" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.points (id BIGINT NOT NULL, jhi_date date NOT NULL, exercise INT, meals INT, alcohol INT, notes VARCHAR(140), user_id BIGINT, CONSTRAINT PK_POINTS PRIMARY KEY (id))]
   ```

Any idea why it’s trying to create my database tables again? Is it because I changed the md5sum?

Do these look like the proper steps you’d take when migrating from an old JHipster-generated schema to a brand new one? The only difference between my old schema and new one is the old one has a `preferences_id` column in the `user` table while the new one has a `user_id` column in the `preferences` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do almost the same: on step 7 I wold relay on liquibase methods for working with the checksum, i.e. I would use [clearCheckSums](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) from command line and then on next run all the checksums are gone be recomputed and if there still is an error about a script that wants to run again like in step 8 then you can use [changelogSync](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) from command line like:

`./liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/health 
--username=postgres clearCheckSums`


`./liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/health 
--username=postgres changelogSync`

Comment: I figured it out by using `update databasechangelog set md5sum=null;` in my target database, which is very similar to your answer, so I'll accept it. I also had to do a number of tweaks to the generated XML, but that wasn't too difficult. I'll write up a blog post about it soon.

Comment: 10x for accepting the answer. Looking forward to your post. Please add a link when it's online, maybe we can gain some insides to use for https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5954

Comment: Blog post published at http://www.jhipster-book.com/#!/news/entry/upgrading-21-points-health-from-v1-to-v4